# How can I create an IAM policy to only allow ec2:RunInstances if hibernation has been enabled on the device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

As the titles says just looking for a request condition I can add to an IAM policy to force users to enable EC2 hibernation mode in order to run instances. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Surprisingly, having consulted the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) it seems to me like that isn't possible, as there's no attribute for shutdown behavior. You might need to create a Service Catalog catalog

Comment: You might be able to code a rule in **AWS Config Rules** that checks for instances with Hibernation disabled and then either activates it or Stops the instance. Yes, it's not as good as blocking the launch of the instance, but it gets the job done. Here's an example for similar needs: [AWS Config: Checking for Compliance with New Managed Rule Options | AWS DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-config-checking-for-compliance-with-new-managed-rule-options/)